# Qt QML fallback component for Webview on Windows

Tags: android, qt, qml, cross-platform, qtquick2

I am trying to create a cross-platform app for Android and Windows with Qt 5.15.2. For Windows, I am using the MinGW 64 bits compiler.
I would like to incorporate a WebView QML component in the Android version of the app. But knowing that MinGW isn't compatible with QtWebView, I'd also like to provide a fallback component for the Windows version. It is important for me to have only one QML file for both platforms.
To do so, I tried to instantiate the WebView dynamically, or a fallback Label, depending on the OS detected at runtime:

```
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

Column {

    property var createdObject

    Component.onCompleted: {
        if(Qt.platform.os=="android") {
            createdObject=Qt.createQmlObject(
                "import QtWebView 1.1
                    
                 WebView {}
                ",
                 embedContainer
            );
        }
        else { //on Windows
            createdObject=Qt.createQmlObject(
                "import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

                 Label {}
                ",
                 embedContainer
            );
        }
    }

    Item {
        id: embedContainer
    }
}
```

This works fine on Windows. However, on Android, the component fail to create with the following error:
**Error: Qt.createQmlObject(): failed to create object:

qrc:/inline:1:18: module "QtWebView" is not installed**

So I tried to add "import QtWebView 1.1" as the third line of the code snippet. It then works on Android, but of course Windows then complains with "**module QtWebView is not installed**", and fails to display the Label.

How should I modify my code to make it work as expected on both platforms ? Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `webview` module in your `.pro` file if you are using `qmake` to build your project.

```
QT += webview
```

As you are building the same project both for Android and Windows, and the `WebView` module is not available in Windows, you need to put it in a test block like:

```
!win32 {
    QT += webview
}
```

which means that if the target platform is not Windows, add `webview` module.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is indeed how my .pro file is configured, I see no issue there